# Raspberry Pi 4, Subversion checksum error, LZ4 decompression failed

Tags: svn, raspberry-pi

I have been using subversion on my RPi4 for over a year without any issues. After one of the latest updates (not sure which one...), I started getting error on any larger Update/Commit/Checkout opperation.

When I do commit or update I usually get: 'LZ4 decompression failed.' I am using newest tortoiseSVN on windows.

My repos where keept on SSD drive connected via USB. I have tried:
Fresh install of raspberry pi OS on a fresh SD card, Creating new repository on both SSD and SSD and finally I bought a new raspberry PI (I ran quite a few things on those, so I will be happy to have a backup anyways)

I have no clue what else to do. My friend who was been using my SVN server has the same issues. My svnserve version is: 1.10.4 and tortoise is 1.14. I am using other SVN servers without any issue.

Also, when I did verify my repositories on all of them I got checksum error. I though that my SSD is faulty, but I don't think it's the case. i used gparted to verify my partition and it seems to be fine. Also as I wrote before, the same issues happen on SD card.

I will be very glad for any help :)
Cheers,
Marcin